# Can access directories using ls but not from Bash

Tags: bash, ssh

I have a bunch of undisciplined users with mail accounts on a server of mine. They never empty their trash or junk folders and the number of files rise to infinity.

I am creating a Bash script to erase those files periodically using cron.

I have done this:

1. create a txt file with a list of directories I want to erase;
2. create a script that will read line by line, every directory and erase everything from `cur` and `new`.

Example of txt file:

```
~/mail/.Junk/cur
~/mail/.Junk/new
~/mail/.Trash/cur
~/mail/. Trash/new
~/mail/.administrative@example.com/.Junk/cur
~/mail/.administrative@example.com/.Junk/new
~/mail/.administrative@example.com/.Trash/cur
~/mail/.administrative@example.com/.Trash/new
~/mail/.finance@example.com/.Junk/cur
~/mail/. finance@example.com/.Junk/new
~/mail/. finance@example.com/.Trash/cur
~/mail/. finance@example.com/.Trash/new
```

I am at the first phase of the script creation where I test if I can access the directories and list their contents.

So I have this script:

```
#!/bin/bash 

while read line 
do 
ls $line
done < ~/directories.txt
```

When I run the script I get the following error:

> ls: cannot access ~/mail/.administrative@example.com/.Junk/new/: No
>   such file or directory

for all directories but If I type

```
ls ~/mail/.administrative@example.com/.Junk/new/
```

it works fine.

why?

Comment: Chron runs your script under root, so `~` points to a different home directory (probably `/root` ). use full paths, and ensure that root has access to the folders and contents.

Comment: Do you run the script (or cron) with the same user as the one when doing the "ls" manually ? Try to echo the `~` path in the script to see if you're in the right place and maybe you'll need to use the absolute path of your home instead of the `~`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Quote your variables!

`while read line` and then doing `ls $line` will not work; you have to use `ls "$line"` to handle whitespace in the variables. Generally, quote your variables when you use them!

If you don't, you're doing to have a huge problem when trying to `rm $line`, if that line is

```
~/mail/. Trash/new
```

Then if you did `ls $line`, it would try to list two folders:

- `~/mail`
- `Trash/new`

In the worst case, if you did an `rm -rf $line`, **you would remove `~/mail` completely**! So, use `ls "$line"` inside your loop. And the same for `rm`.

In fact, the most robust way to read a file line-by-line and properly handle whitespace is [explained here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001):

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    ls "$line"
done < "$file"
```

The `-r` prevents backslashes from being expanded, and `IFS=` helps in case that a line starts or ends with a whitespace, which the shell would trim otherwise.

#### Do not use paths that need to be expanded!

If your text file contains paths that will only later be expanded, the path will change depending on who executes the script where. Here, `~` will be expanded to the user's home path at the time of execution, so if you are running the script as `root`, it will start from `/root`, and not from the user's home at the point of creating the text file.

Therefore, store the full paths in your file.